# Add a new Column to an existing IdentityServer4 Model

Tags: entity-framework, identityserver4

Can I add a new column to the existing `Clients` table, which is autogenerated by the IdentityServer4.EntityFramework ?

Comment: I'm not too sure about adding extra columns but have you considered using the `ClientProperties` table? This allows you to associate any number of Key/Value pairs with individual clients.

Comment: Actually I didn't considered this option.. how could I have missed it. I think it will do the the job. Thank you :)